# How OSPF Support Classless Domains

Tags: networking, routing, ospf

Link state Packet in OSPF contains :
1.Identification Number of sender.
2.Sequence Number.
3.Network Number.
4.Cost or metric.
5.Next Hop.

i am not able to understand how OSPF support variable length Sub-netting, looking at the contents of link state packet i don't get any hint.Please explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without beeing an OSPF guru, I'd say that you are looking at a OSPF v1 packet, which, like RIPv1 is a very old routing protocol and might not support variable length subnetting.

OSPF v2 supports VLSM, and you should take a look at [the OSPFv2 RFC paper](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1247) to see how the Link State Advertisements are built.

Each LSA packet contains the network mask for the networks the router is announcing :

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |            LS age             |      Options  |      2        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                        Link State ID                          |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                     Advertising Router                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                     LS sequence number                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |         LS checksum           |             length            |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                         Network Mask                          |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                        Attached Router                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                              ...                              |
```